# Wrong page numbering(ToC-LoT)-Empty pages before ToC-

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, tocloft

First of all I am sorry for my not minimum WE. I will explain why it's not... I am creating a ToC in a book-class document. ToC starts at page iii(I am using roman numbering) and ends at iv. The ToC entry though indicates that ToC starts at iv.

[image]

Another issue is that before ToC there two blank pages(i,ii) but I don't know how to make them dissapear.

The last issue has to do with LoT. Despite including LoT before arabic page numbering, LoT starts on page 1. I tried `\setcounter{page}{xi}` but it is indicated that there is a number missing.

How can I resolve those issues. Here comes my WE(despite 8 errors pdf is produced). The reason why it's not MWE is that I wanted to add chapters and section in order to create a    two page ToC.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftparskip{0pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{-5pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesubsecskip{-8pt}
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{-1pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-50pt}
 \setlength\cftbeforefigskip{-5pt}
\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{-5pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lofwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lof}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lotwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lot}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.8mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo.jpg}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}
 \begin {center}
 \large
{University\\Faculty\\Department\\Group}\\
\vspace{2cm}
\HRule\\ \vspace{0.7cm} \textbf{\LARGE Title}\\ \vspace{0.7cm}\HRule
\vspace{2cm}
{\La rge Author}\\ \vspace{2cm}
supervision\\
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large Prof\\
\Large Supervisor}\\ \vspace{4cm}
Month Year
\end{center}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\textcolor{blue}{\chapter*{\contentsname}}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\textcolor{blue}{\tocwithouttitle}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

\textcolor{blue}{\chapter*{Abstract}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}{\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}

This is the abstract

\textcolor{blue}{\chapter*{Aknowledgements}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Aknowledgements}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Aknowledgements}}{\MakeUppercase{Aknowledgements}}

These are aknowledgements

\textcolor{blue}{\chapter*{LoF}}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{LoF}}{\MakeUppercase{LoF}}
\textcolor{blue}{\lofwithouttitle}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LoF}

 \textcolor{blue}{\chapter*{LoT}}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{LoT}}{\MakeUppercase{LoT}}
\textcolor{blue}{\lotwithouttitle}
%\setcounter{page}{xi}<----Error missing number/seems it doesn't accept roman like that
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LoT}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introductionThis is the introductionThis is the introductionThis is the introductionThis is the introductionThis is the introductionThis is the introductionThis is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.v.This is the introduction.This is the introductionThis is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the     introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.This is the introduction.

\newpage
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla  bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{intro}
bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
 bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{intro}
bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Intro}
 bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
 \section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{intro}
bla bla bla\\

 \newpage
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Intro}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{intro}
bla bla bla\\

\chapter{Theory}
This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.This is about theory.

 \newpage
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
 bla bla bla\\
 \section{Theo}
 bla bla bla\\
 \subsection{theo}
 bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Theo}
 bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{theo}
 bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{theo}
bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Theo}
bla  bla bla\\
\se ction{Theo}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{theo}
bla  bla bla\\

\chapter{Experiment}
This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This  is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about  epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This    is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about     epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This     is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about     epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This    is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about epxeriment.This is about     epxeriment.

\newpage
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{exp}
bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{exp}
bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{exp}
bla bla bla\\

\newpage
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\section{Exp}
bla bla bla\\
\subsection{exp}
 bla bla bla\\

\end{document}
```

---

My real ToC, with better spacing is that

[image]

Comment: where is the sense of having the TOC in the TOC? I suppose that nobody will have a look into the TOC where he can find the TOC ... ;-)

Comment: Is your purpose to write the frontmatter pages in blue?

Comment: @Herbert:Thank you for your answer! You are right about that but I want my theses to be perfect!

Comment: @egreg:Thank you very much for your comment! Yes that's true!But it doesn't matter!

Comment: @Thanos: If you want it perfect then do not use such an entry in the TOC

Comment: @Herbert: You may be right but this is something which is not working properly. After a lot of tries I found out that the entry ToC refers to the last page of ToC, which is something I don't understand why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand some things: (1) why putting the table of contents in the table of contents; (2) why trying to squeeze the table of contents in such a horrible way; (3) why using a different color for the front matter.

However, here's a way that makes also your input way easier.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftparskip{0pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-50pt}

% VALUES BELOW ARE QUESTIONABLE
%\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{-5pt}
%\setlength\cftbeforesubsecskip{-8pt}
%\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{-1pt}
% \setlength\cftbeforefigskip{-5pt}
%\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{-5pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\color{\currentprintcolor}%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \thechapter. \fi\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\color{\currentprintcolor}\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\color{\currentprintcolor}\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[C]{\color{\currentprintcolor}\thepage}
}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.5pt}

\newcommand{\currentprintcolor}{black}
\newenvironment{printinblue}
  {\cleardoublepage\renewcommand{\currentprintcolor}{blue}\color{blue}}
  {\cleardoublepage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\withouttitle}[1]{\@starttoc{#1}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.8mm}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo.jpg}
 \end{center}
 \begin {center}
 \large
{University\\Faculty\\Department\\Group}\\
\vspace{2cm}
\HRule\\ \vspace{0.7cm} \textbf{\LARGE Title}\\ \vspace{0.7cm}\HRule
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large Author}\\ \vspace{2cm}
supervision\\
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large Prof\\
\Large Supervisor}\\ \vspace{4cm}
Month Year
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\begin{printinblue}

\chapter{\contentsname}
\withouttitle{toc}

\chapter{Abstract}

This is the abstract

\chapter{Acknowledgements}

These are acknowledgements

\chapter{\listfigurename}
\withouttitle{lof}

\chapter{\listtablename}
\withouttitle{lot}

\end{printinblue}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

...    

\end{document}
```

If you could remove the "Glenn" chapter style I would be happier.

---

Many things went wrong with your input. First of all, the page numbers: if you put `\addcontentsline` at the end of the list (after your `\tocwithouttitle`, to be precise), the referenced page is the *last* one.

Your usage of `\textcolor` is wrong: `\textcolor{blue}{\tocwithouttitle}` gives scores of errors, because LaTeX tries to typeset the table of contents in a horizontal box: just like `\mbox{\tableofcontents}` that *can't* work.

So the best way is to change the text color for the duration of the front matter, which I do with the `printinblue` environment. It's also necessary to modify the way headers and footers are typeset, so I load `fancyhdr` and do the necessary setting for getting the same output as with the standard `book` class setup.

Using `\frontmatter` frees you from manually inserting the marks and the references for the table of contents. Moreover it sets the page numbering to roman numerals automatically; with `\mainmatter` you select arabic numerals for the page numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your code is working for my WE, but I cannot get it to work with my thesis. ToC, LoF, LoT are blank. I will try a bit more. There is one issue though... Your blue enviroment is awesome!!! Lastly, you don't like Glenn, right?:)

Comment: I got it work-almost... ToC, LoF and LoT are printed but after LoT there are 2 blank pages(1,2 with uppercase:"Table of Contents") which means that the first chapter starts at page 3...

Comment: @Thanos You probably have some dangling `\cleardoublepage`. Difficult to tell. And no, I won't be looking at the several megabytes of your thesis, sorry. :)

Comment: There isn't any `\cleardoublepage`. It crosses my mind that the nasty work is being done by "subfiles". I thought of adding a `\clearemptydoublepage`-like command in order to replace `\cleardoublepage` using `\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage` but if I use it in my preable, it's applied on all chapters(I thought so) but if I apply it locally on the subfile it is again changed everywhere. I will try a bit more!Oh, btw I never recall asking you to check my thesis ;) Ciao amico mio!

Comment: It is really `subfiles` that is doing the nasty work... I used your code in a different way. I made chapter one a new .tex and I "subfiled" it in main. These two pages are left blank. I will try to see what's going on in subfiles.cls...

Comment: I took a look at subfiles.cls but it doesn't to be relevant. There is nothing there stating anything about `doublepage` or something similar...

Comment: I tried something else:I copied the code from the subfile and pasted it directly into the main file. The thing is that again there are two extra blank pages between LoT and first chapter....

Comment: I don't know about "subfiles". The problem is clearly that something does `\null` or something like that, that is, it inserts something invisible before the `\cleardoublepage` that's issued by the first `\chapter`. It could be a `\vspace*` or `\mbox{}` or whatever.

Comment: I found something!If I remove `\mainmatter` this double page isn't added. But this can't be accepted as a solution because I can't have roman page numbering and 0 chapter numbering. So I tried to insert `\frontmatter` in curly braces,i.e. `{\frontmatter ...} \subfile{chap1}` but in that case LoT is placed on page 1. I also tried to completely remove `\frontmatter` and add only `\mainmater` after `\begin{document}` while adding `\chapter*{ToC}` and `\pagenumbering{roman}` but again LoT is printed on p.1. Then I placed `\mainmatter` after LoT but in that case I'm dealing with doublepage issue.

Comment: I also tried `openany` in book class options. Apparently new chapters didn't necessarily start at an odd page, but after LoT there was an empty page with roman numbering(uppercase stating LoT). Then there was again an empty page with arabic numbering(uppercase stated LoC again!). Then there was the first page of the chapter. I got the same behaviour when adding `\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother` between LoT and chapter. There is something wrong with either page numbering(roman/arabic) or front/main-matter. When using only front or main there are no extra empty pages...

Comment: :I found out what the problem was...The first chapter started with `\textcolor{blue}{\chapter{Name}}`...This was adding blank pages. When it was removed the blank pages vanished! However I want to have chapter headings blue... I tried \chapter{\textcolor{blue}{Name}} but it's not working. I also tried your blue enviroment but the output is still in black...How can it be in blue?

Comment: False alarm...Your environment is `printinblue` not `printblue`... It is working with no problems!!!Thank you!!!